# Advanced Sql generations Options window has radio buttons disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

If I open GridView’s *Smart Tasks* pop up --> *Configure Data Source*, then after *Choose you data connection* window I’m presented with the *Configure the Select Statement* window. This window also has *Advanced* button, which opens *Advanced Sql Generations Options* window. But both radio buttons in that window are faded out and thus I’m not able to select any of the two buttons.

Any idea why the two radio buttons are disabled?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the most common cause is that there is no primary key for the table defined in the database that is part of your SELECT statement.

Make sure that:

1. You have a primary key column that is selected in the list of columns
2. Your primary key column does not have a default value.

Comment: I used SqlDataSource, which should support it

Comment: Check the underlying table in your database.  Make sure that it has a primary key field with the Identity property set, and that this field is part of your SQL SELECT statement in your SqlDataSource.

Comment: I've set DataKeyNames, but it still didn't work. Anyways, why would setting DataKeyNames have any effect on whether radio buttons are enabled or not?

Comment: Did you make sure the table in the database has a primary key, with the identity property set?  is that field part of your SELECT statement?

Comment: I was sure that field I've set in DB was also a primary key, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Anyhow, I tried it using another table and it works now. Anyways, thank you all for your kind help

Answer (score 1):

Have you set primary key(s) for the tabel(s)?